# Visual Studio Mac 2017 hangs on build

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to build my Xamarin.Forms app but the build always hangs at the same stage (Android and iOS build) and I would really like to figure out why. Visual studio then fully hangs and can only be force-closed.[image]

This only happens in one specific branch, but I need to find out, what's wrong.
I cannot see anything from the log or maybe I am looking at the wrong log. I would really appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Buildlog:

Building Tool.iOS (Debug)
Build started 1/24/2019 10:54:15 AM.

---

Project "/Users/username/Projects/Company/tool/XamarinApp/Tool/Services/Pairing.csproj" (Build target(s)):

Target _HandlePackageFileConflicts:
    /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.500/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.ConflictResolution.targets(41,5): message NETSDK1041: Encountered conflict between 'Reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/netstandard.library/2.0.3/build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll' and 'Reference:/Users/username/.nuget/packages/system.net.networkinformation/4.1.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll'.  NETSDK1033: Choosing 'Reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/netstandard.library/2.0.3/build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.1.2.0' is greater than '4.1.0.0'.
Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
  Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target CoreGenerateAssemblyInfo:
  Skipping target "CoreGenerateAssemblyInfo" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target CoreCompile:
  Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target GenerateBuildDependencyFile:
  Skipping target "GenerateBuildDependencyFile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
    Pairing -> /Users/username/Projects/Company/tool/XamarinApp/Tool/Services/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/Pairing.dll

Comment: Do you have any build logs at all?

Comment: Just attached..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I proceeded as follows. I tried to build each project separately to see, which one is to blame. The platform-independent one blocked the build. Then I used msbuild in Terminal to get more information and it spat out that it could not resolve a GitVersion nuget. I removed it and voilá it worked.